# Django CBVs to return a JsonResponse?

Tags: django, django-views

I have been using Django for some time, but running into some issues with trying something new.

I have built API's with Django-Rest-Framework using Class Based Views, and I have also built API's using Function based views returning a `JsonResponse`

Now what I am tasked to do is use CBV's to return a `JsonResponse` without using DRF. I am trying to produce a simple get request

```
class BusinessDetailView(DetailView):
    model = BusinessDetail

    def get_queryset(self):
        business = BusinessDetail.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return JsonResponse({'business': list(business)})
```

Using the models `pk` I keep running into issues with this simple request. I am getting a  `TypeError 'BusinessDetail' object is not iterable` and if I make some small changes and override `get_object` I'll get the same error, or I'll even get a `'BusinessDetail' object is not callable`

Does anybody have any tips with using CBVs to return Json, without using DRF?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would try something like this:

```
class BusinessDetailView(DetailView):
    model = BusinessDetail

    def get_queryset(self):
        business = BusinessDetail.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return business

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        data = serializers.serialize("json", queryset)
        return JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)
```

Comment: Ahhh. The serialization. Thank you so much. Greatly appreciated!